# Категориальные признаки или OneHotEncoder

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, машинное-обучение, scikit-learn

Дамы и господа, добрый вечер. Решил попробовать свои силы на kaggle и сразу немного уткнулся лицом в стену. Вот кейс: [Mercedes-Benz Greener Manufacturing](https://www.kaggle.com/c/mercedes-benz-greener-manufacturing)
Первые фичи - категориальные. Собственно решил их конвертировать в {0, 1}  при помощи 1) OneHotEncoder() 
`one_ = OneHotEncoder() 
encoded_X = one_.fit(X_train)`

А когда не получилось, попробовал в "лоб"

`for i in range(1,9): 
    one = pd.get_dummies(X_train[X_train.columns[i]]) 
    X_train = X_train.join(one, how='right') 
    X_train.drop(X_train.columns[i], axis=1)`

В обоих случаях выдает ошибку.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так. Спасибо!

Comment: Замените картинку кодом в читаемом виде.

Comment: 1 вариант
`one_ = OneHotEncoder()`
`encoded_X = one_.fit(X_train)`

2 вариант
`for i in range(1,9):
    one = pd.get_dummies(X_train[X_train.columns[i]])
    X_train = X_train.join(one, how='right')
    X_train.drop(X_train.columns[i], axis=1)`

Comment: Поправте вопрос. Коментировать не надо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
In [61]: df.select_dtypes(exclude=['object']) \
           .join(pd.get_dummies(df.select_dtypes(include=['object'])))
Out[61]:
        ID       y  X10  X11  X12  X13  X14  ...   X8_s  X8_t  X8_u  X8_v  X8_w  X8_x  X8_y
0        0  130.81    0    0    0    1    0  ...      0     0     0     0     0     0     0
1        6   88.53    0    0    0    0    0  ...      0     0     0     0     0     0     0
2        7   76.26    0    0    0    0    0  ...      0     0     0     0     0     1     0
3        9   80.62    0    0    0    0    0  ...      0     0     0     0     0     0     0
4       13   78.02    0    0    0    0    0  ...      0     0     0     0     0     0     0
5       18   92.93    0    0    0    0    1  ...      1     0     0     0     0     0     0
6       24  128.76    0    0    0    0    1  ...      1     0     0     0     0     0     0
7       25   91.91    0    0    0    0    1  ...      0     0     0     0     0     0     0
8       27  108.67    0    0    0    0    1  ...      0     0     0     0     0     0     0
9       30  126.99    0    0    0    0    1  ...      0     0     0     0     0     0     0
...    ...     ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...  ...    ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...   ...
4199  8395   88.24    1    0    0    0    0  ...      0     0     0     0     0     0     0
4200  8397  108.59    0    0    0    0    1  ...      0     0     0     0     1     0     0
4201  8399  107.39    0    0    0    0    0  ...      0     0     0     0     0     0     0
4202  8402  123.34    0    0    0    0    0  ...      0     0     0     0     0     0     0
4203  8403   85.71    0    0    0    0    1  ...      0     0     0     0     0     0     0
4204  8405  107.39    0    0    0    0    1  ...      0     0     0     0     0     0     0
4205  8406  108.77    0    0    0    0    0  ...      0     0     0     0     0     0     0
4206  8412  109.22    0    0    1    1    0  ...      0     0     0     0     0     0     0
4207  8415   87.48    0    0    0    0    1  ...      0     0     1     0     0     0     0
4208  8417  110.85    0    0    0    0    0  ...      0     0     0     0     1     0     0

[4209 rows x 565 columns]
```

Comment: Спасибо!
Если можно, подскажите, где ошибка в моем синтаксисе?