# Новый столбец в pd.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

У меня есть DataFrame, в котором первый и второй столбец - текст. Соответственно хочу узнать среднюю длину слова для каждого значения для одного из столбцов.

Написал следующую функцию:

```
def av_len(a,c):
    column_n = a.columns[c] + '_word_len'
    sum = 0
    number = []
    for i in range(a.shape[0]):
        df = p.findall(a.iloc[i][c])
        for j in range(len(df)):
            sum += len((df)[j])
        total = sum/len(df)
        number.append(total)
        sum = 0
    a = a.assign(column_n = pd.Series(number))
    return a[:5]
```

Подаем DataFrame, указываем номер столбца, получаем еще один столбец с нужным параметром. Проблема в том, что новый столбец должен иметь имя "*исходный_столбец_word_len*"

Это я попытался сделать при помощи:

```
column_n = a.columns[c] + '_word_len'
```

и

```
a = a.assign(column_n = pd.Series(number))
```

Однако имя новой колонки все равно *"column_n"*. Подскажите, как оптимальнее всего реализовать данную идею?

Мне это необходимо, чтобы для каждого отдельного столбца с текстом создавалась своя колонка с измеряемым параметром.

Comment: Вы можете привести небольшой пример анонимных данных (в виде текста) и желаемый результирующий DF? Вы ищете среднюю длину слова в столбце для каждой строки?

Comment: Да, в столбце для каждой строки. Я могу как-нибудь вставить строку-результат из Jupyter Notebook сюда в читаемом виде?

Comment: Строку или DF ?

Comment: Подскажите, как вы тут вставили в ответе?
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/681724/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8-onehotencoder

Comment: Я использую `ipython` - консольный аналог `Jupyter`. Вы можете попробовать сохранить данные как CSV: `df.head(5).to_csv(r'c:/temp/aaa.csv')` и запостить CSV в ваш вопрос

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поменяйте:

```
a = a.assign(column_n = pd.Series(number))
```

на

```
a[column_n] = number
```

НО вложенный цикл - это **очень неэффективный** способ. Наверняка можно использовать векторизированный подход. Но без примера входных и выходных данных - трудно сказать точно, т.к. непонятно что такое и как выглядит переменная `p`.

Comment: Да, это работает. По поводу вложенного цикла буду смотреть. Спасибо

Comment: Совет - создайте новый вопрос с небольшим примером данных в виде текста или CSV и ожидаемый результат. Я уверен на 99%, что можно найти гораздо более эффективное решение.